# Conjugacy class in matrix ring

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

Let $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ be the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over the reals and $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})^*$ the set of invertible such matrices. 
Consider any $A \in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $ A^{2}=-I$, where $I$ is the identity element in $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$. 
We say that $A,B \in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ are conjugate in $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ if there exists $C \in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})^*$ with $B=C^{-1}AC$.

What is the conjugacy class of $A$?

My main problem is that $S:=\{A \in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$: $ A^{2}=-I\}$ is neither a subring nor an ideal so I cannot use any "structural result" to show what the conjugacy class is.

I tried the classic and sometimes efficient "brutal force" approach and calculated that the matrices in $S$ are of the form $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b  \\
-\frac{a^2+1}{b} & -a \ \end{array} \right)$, with $b \neq 0$. Then, I conjugated any of these matrices by an arbitrary invertible matrix but this did not lead anywhere.

Any idea as to what the conjugacy class should be?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got it! Try to prove that it is $S$ itself.

**Hint:** It would be enough to prove that for any $A\in S$, there is a basis, according to which the matrix of $v\mapsto Av$ is $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$. I think, you can start out of any nonzero vector $v_1\in\Bbb R^2$, maybe the easiest to consider $v_1:=\pmatrix{0\\1}$. Now $v_2$ is given by $[A]_{v_1,v_2}$.

Comment: I had a feeling it was $S$ itself! At least now I know what I have to do. Thanks!

Comment: I had doubts, but then checked, and it works... Have you known that, putting the basis vectors in the culomns to a matrix $B$ then $[A]_B=B^{-1}AB$? That's why we look for such a basis.

Comment: What do you mean by $[A]_B$?

Comment: The matrix of $v\mapsto Av$ w.r.t. the basis given by $B$.

Comment: Ok. Now it makes sense. Very clever idea, thank you!